# POST request using sockets C#

Tags: c#, sockets, post

I'm trying to make an auction sniper for a site. To place a bid you need to send 4 parameters(and cookies of course) to /auction/place_bid. I need to use sockets, not HttpWebRequest. Here's the code:

```
        string request1 = "POST /auction/place_bid HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: *host here*\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)\r\nAccept: /*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\nX-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n" + cookies +"\r\n";
        string request3 = "token=" + token + "&aid=" + aid + "&bidReq=" + ptzReq + "&recaptcha_challenge_field=" + rcf + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + rrf+"\r\n\r\n";
        string request2 = "Content-Length: " + (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(request1+request3)+23).ToString() + "\r\n";
        byte[] dataSent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request1+request2+request3);
        byte[] dataReceived = new byte[10000];
        Socket socket = ConnectSocket(server, 80);
        if (socket == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        socket.Send(dataSent, dataSent.Length, 0);
        int bytes = 0;
        string page = "";
        do
        {
            bytes = socket.Receive(dataReceived, dataReceived.Length, 0);
            page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceived, 0, bytes);
        }
        while (bytes > 0);

        return page;
```

When I'm trying to receive the webpage Visual Studio says that "Operation on an unblocked socket cannot be completed immediatly", when I add

```
socket.Blocking = true;
```

My application stops responsing and after ~1 minute it returns page, but it's empty! When I'm trying to make a GET request it works perfect. I hope you will help me. By the way, this is the first time when I use sockets so my code is pretty bad, sorry about that.

*I'm using a ConnectSocket class, which was given as an example at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) (The link leads to Russian MSDN, sorry, I didn't find the same article in English, but you'll understand the code anyway)

Comment: How have you determined that `HttpWebRequest` is slow here? For sending a basic request/response it should be fine, only hampered by the intatubez...

Comment: I'm not sure that using Sockets would make things any faster. After all the network is the slow bit not the processing on the local machine. Perhaps there's just a lot of network latency between you and the site?

Comment: What makes you think that synchronous socket comms will outperform HttpWebRequest? How many requests are you pumping out such that this is so problematic? We rolled our own HTTP stack, but this was to make literally hundreds of requests per second... unless you're really hammering it, HttpWebRequest should do you fine. It's a non-trivial undertaking.

Comment: By the time you get it right it will be (at least) as slow as HttpWebrequest.

Comment: Forget about `HttpWebRequest`, please, help me to do out with sockets.

Comment: You're not going to get better performance than HttpWebRequest by cut'n'pasting example code that clearly isn't written for volume performance. If you really want to gear up to making lots of connections, investigate the async methods of HttpWebRequest (and its myriad of options) and then, only if strictly necessary and after A LOT of careful measurement, use the async socket methods. Your code as it stands will never be improvement to what HttpWebRequest offers.

Comment: I don't need a lot of connections, I need to make 1 request a time, and it should be as fast as it possible.

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` will be faster than anything you can hand-roll using sockets.  Trust us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-Length` header should indicate the size of the content. You're setting it to the total size of your headers ***and*** content.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(request1+request3)+23).ToString()
```

Since the content part of your message is just `request3`, the server is patiently waiting for `ByteCount(request1)+23` more bytes of content which you never send.

Try this instead:

```
"Content-Length: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(request3).ToString() + "\r\n"
```

---

Another issue looks like your loop:

```
do
{
    bytes = socket.Receive(dataReceived, dataReceived.Length, 0);
    page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataReceived, 0, bytes);
}
while (bytes > 0);
```

Since non-blocking socket operations always return immediately whether or not they've completed yet, you need a loop that keeps calling `Receive()` until the operation has actually completed. Here, if the call to `Receive()` returns `0` (which it almost certainly will the first time) you exit the loop.

You should at least change it to `while (bytes <= 0)` which would get you at least some data (probably just the first packet's worth or so). Ideally, you should keep calling `Receive()` until you see the `Content-Length` header in the reply, then continue calling `Receive()` until the end of the headers, then read `Content-Length` more bytes.

Since you're using sockets, you really have to re-implement the HTTP protocol.

Comment: It keeps saying that "Operation on an unblocked socket cannot be completed immediatly". Thanks for you answer anyway!

Comment: That's how nonblocking sockets work. The calls to `Send()` and `Receive()` return immediately and the socket does its thing in the background. You need to wait until the server has had time to respond. If it hasn't gotten any data yet, you'll get that 'error' which really means to just try again.

Answer (score 3):

As people already has pointed out: `HttpWebRequest` is not the cause of you performance issues. Switching to a socket implementation will not affect anything.

The fact is that the `HttpWebRequest` can do zillions of stupid things if it want to, and it will still be faster than the time it takes to get stuff from the webserver.

Switching to a socket implementation might speed things up if you have good knowledge when it comes to sockets AND the http protocol. You clearly do not have that, so I would recommend that you go back to `HttpWebRequest` again.

You might want to use `WebClient` if you are going to fetch lots of pages from the same webserver since it will keep the connection alive.

### Update

> I don't need a lot of connections, I need to make 1 request a time, and it should be as fast as it possible

Well. Then it doesn't really matter which implementation you use. The network latency will ALWAYS be a lot larger than the actual HTTP client implementation. Building a HTTP request doesn't take very much resources, parsing a response doesn't do that either.